# Match only the begining of the string in a MongoDB query

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I am simply attempting to match a snippet of text to the begining of a string with mongoDB.

I have tried a plethora of structures that just are not working, I assume the query should be something like:

```
var dataList = _dataService.GetCollectionQueryModel<User>(
    Query.And(
        Query.EQ("IsActive", true),
        Query.Matches("FullName", "/^" + query + "/")
    )
);
```

However that returns nothing, but if i pass query in alone then i will get data returned but it will match any part of the firstname, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Query.Matches("FullName", "^" + query)`?

Comment: @Wizard I had not but that did it!